# A trigonometric integral from characters of $SU(2)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to know if there is a nice way to calculate the following integral which arises from an inner product of characters of $SU(2)$:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\sin((2n+2)\theta)}{\sin(2\theta)} + \frac{\sin^2((n+1)\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\right)^2 \sin^2\theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta$$

Thanks!

Comment: May we assume that $n$ is non-negative integer?